# PHP array submitted to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure if this question has been asked before, so please note if it's duplicate.

The top line is a PHP merged array that I'm trying to send in AJAX to another page.

I'm having trouble finding what goes in the "?" or how to format it.

```
<?php $_SESSION['pdfData'] = array_merge_recursive($count, $qty); ?>
```

```js
$.ajax({ 
 type: "POST",
 url: "indexMenu-sm-pdf.php",
 data: { 
            ? 
        },
 dataType: "JSON", 
 success: function(data){
     console.log("Good.");
 },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
 } 
});
```

I understand that the built-in function json_encode() but i lack the know-how. And I've been reading about serialization. Is one better than the other?

My main questions are: 
**What goes into the "?" as $_Session['pdfData'] can not be sent.**
And
**Is there a difference is using json_encode vs. serialization for this issue?**

Comment: indexMenu-sm-pdf.php could just read the data from the session

Comment: The meta header the company is using is preventing the session from being passed. While I wish it was that easy... this is was the next step I thought of (albeit, much more difficult).

Comment: what meta header? that's a new one.

Comment: Typically, because PHP is NOT a single page application you'd share data between pages via session or data fetches. Is there a specific reason you want to AJAX data between pages directly without any PHP code in between for data handling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: "indexMenu-sm-pdf.php",
    data: { 
            paramName: <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['pdfData']) ?>
        },
    dataType: "JSON", 
    success: function(data){
        console.log("Good.");
    },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    } 
});
```

Replace `paramName` with the name of the `$_POST` parameter that `indexMenu-sm-pdf.php` is expecting to get the PDF data from. `json_encode()` will output the contents of the session variable in the form of a Javascript literal.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Barmar is right. But you can also split the php and the js code.
Set a DOM element in your page with the php value and access it via js within your ajax call.

See the following example:

1.) Set the DOM element on your page

```
<div id="jsDomElementPdf" style="display:none">
  <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['pdfData']); ?>
</div>
```

2.) Access the value in your script

```
let paramName = document.getElementById("jsDomElementPdf") || '';

if(paramName){
   $.ajax({ 
     type: "POST",
     url: "indexMenu-sm-pdf.php",
     data: { 
        paramName: paramName
     },
     dataType: "JSON", 
     success: function(data){
       console.log("Good.");
      },
     error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    } 
  });
}
```